# colored triangle where the color changes over time

Tags: opengl, c++

I am trying to draw a triangle which changes color over time. My implementation is by using uniform variable.

my fragment shader-

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;
uniform float var;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(var*0.2, var*0.333, var*0.7, 1.0f);
}
```

in render loop

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    time = 1.0f*fabs(sin(glfwGetTime()*3.1416f));
    processInput(window);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    shader1.use();
    shader1.setFloat("var", time);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glfwPollEvents();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```

But the triangle goes blue to dark. What is missing?

Comment: FragColor will output colors between (0,0,0) (black) and (0.2,0.333,0.7) (blue). What colors are you trying to get?

Comment: It should go from dark to blue to dark to blue to dark to blue .... is it not doing that? is it staying dark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `sin()` will only fluctuate between -1 to 1, and u turn that into 0 - 1 by using the `fabs` function, which doesn't get amplified (multiplication by `1.0f`). so the line

```
time = 1.0f*fabs(sin(glfwGetTime()*3.1416f));
```

will result in a vec4 color range of `(0, 0, 0, 1)` to `(0.2, 0.333, 0.7, 1)` in a **uniform** pace for all `rgb` elements. To get better results, define 3 variables and calculate the color coefficient for each `RGB` element separately, whcih results in a **non-uniform pace** for the color change, something like this (i use pseudo-code):

```
...
time = glfwGetTime();
float r_amp = fmod(time, 0.5f);
float g_amp = fmod(time, 1.0f);
float b_amp = fmod(time, 2.0f);
...

shader1.use();
shader1.setFloat("var_r", r_amp);
shader1.setFloat("var_g", g_amp);
shader1.setFloat("var_b", b_amp);
...
```

and in your fragment shader clamp those values to a 0 to 1 range (or do that on the cpu side):

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;
uniform float var_r;
uniform float var_g;
uniform float var_b;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(var_r*2, var_g*1, var_b*0.5, 1.0f);
}
```

you can also resort to `sin()` for fluctuations as you did initially but u need to multiply `time` by a different coefficient for each `var` and then calculate the `sin()`. for now `fmod()` will be much easier to understand but later on especially in performance-critical settings, `sin()` is faster than `fmod()`